# Custom Sort by numbers and "-"

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to sort a range of cells and can't seem to get the result that I want. The range of cells contain values such as:
1-11-1
1-10-2
1-12-1
1-11-2
1-10-1
1-12-2

Result that I am looking for is:
1-10-1
1-11-1
1-12-1
1-10-2
1-11-2
1-12-2

I have tried multiple different custom sorts(###-###-### and "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" ), but cannot get the correct result. Is it even possible to get the sort results that I want or is a macro needed maybe? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are they dates? Or does it represent something else entirely?

Comment: Something else entirely. I have them formatted as text in Excel.

Comment: Add auxiliary columns with formulas splitting the values by the parts, and containing each part respectively. Sort the entire table first by first part, by second part, and finally by third part column.

Comment: Thanks a lot omegastipes that worked great! Had to sort by first part, third part, finally second part to get the result I wanted. Thanks again, such a time saver. Voted your comment useful.

Answer (score 0):

Split text by "-" into columns.

Sort data by columns: 1, 3 and 2. In 4. column add formula to concatenate text from three columns into one string ;)

That's all!

Here is a simple macro. Fill free to change it:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rng As Range, lstRow As Integer

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    lstRow = rng.Rows.Count

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & lstRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C" & lstRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & lstRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & lstRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D1")
    rng.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A1,""-"",B1,""-"",C1)"
    rng.AutoFill ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & lstRow)

   'now you can copy sorted data whatever you  want ;)

    Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note: before you use above macro, make sure that the data exists in a single column: A - in this case.

Cheers, Maciej